# OpenAI Whisper API: Get token/minute usage from response

Tags: openai-api, openai-whisper

I am using openAI whisper to convert voice to text: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/create

the json response is

```json
{
  "text": "some text"
}
```

the response data return only one `text` field and has no other information

I want to know how much tokens I have used, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**There are no tokens for OpenAI Audio API endpoints. You pay per minute.**

As stated on the official [OpenAI website](https://openai.com/pricing):

> As of March 2023, using the OpenAI Whisper audio model, you pay $0.006/minute
> (rounded to the nearest second).

[image: Screenshot]

*Note: You can't get minute usage from the OpenAI response like you can get token usage when using other OpenAI API endpoints. You need to write code and get the audio duration manually.*

Comment: no token, so it is free? I want to keep track of my users usage

Comment: No, it's not free. It costs $0.006/minute.

Comment: so how can I keep track of my user usage?

Comment: The only option I see is that you track file length in minutes.

Comment: I know, but how can I obtain the `minute` (or `token` or whatever) from the response???

Comment: You can't get that from the OpenAI response. You need to write code manually. If you're using Python, see [How to get the duration of audio in Python?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-duration-of-audio-in-python/).

Comment: So if I send a 6 second audio, will that be charged as 1 minute or as 6 seconds?

Comment: @GroovyDotCom Honestly, I haven't tested this. I think the easiest and most reliable way to figure this out is to simply send a 6-second audio to the Whisper API endpoint. Then check in the [usage dashboard](https://platform.openai.com/account/usage) under *Daily usage breakdown* how much you were charged for a 6-second audio. If you'll do this, please come back to me and let me know how much you were charged, because I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS I did in this way:

```
    /**
     * Transcribe audio file
     * @param {string} outputFilePath
     * @returns {Promise<string>}
     */
    async transcribeAudio(outputFilePath) {

        const url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions';
        const apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;
        const language = 'pt';

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', createReadStream(path.resolve(outputFilePath)));
        formData.append('model', 'whisper-1');
        formData.append('response_format', 'verbose_json');
        formData.append('language', language);

        const headers = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`, ...formData.getHeaders()};

        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            const req = https.request(url, {method: 'POST', headers: headers}, (res) => {
                let data = '';
                res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', () => {
                    const response = JSON.parse(data);

                    console.log(`transcribeAudio response: "${response.text}" - Seconds: ${response.duration}`);

                    const segments = response && response.segments ? response.segments : [];
                    const transcription = segments.map((segment) => segment.text).join('\n');

                    resolve(transcription);
                });
            });

            req.on('error', (error) => {
                console.error('error on transcribe mp3 audio in openai whisper', error);
                reject(error);
            });

            formData.pipe(req);
        });
    }
```